# Scraping Data with Commas in Python

Tags: python

I'm scraping a table using Python with requests and lxml. The data from the table is found using tree.xpath and added to lists which are written to a CSV file. Unfortunately, the rows in one of the table's columns contains commas, which is changing the number of values in the list.

Example:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://url.com/table')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

list1 = tree.xpath('//*[@id=block]/div/tr[*]/td[1]/a/text()')
list2 = tree.xpath('//*[@id=block]/div/tr[*]/td[2]/a/text()')
```

Table that I am Scraping:

```
Column1 | Column2
A,B,C     X
D,E       Y
F,G,H     Z
```

Current Output:

```
print list1
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']

print list2
['X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Preferred Output:

```
print list1
['a b c', 'd e', 'f g h']

print list2
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

I've had trouble finding a suitable solution. Is there an easy way to remove the commas from the values or keep the commas while using a different delimiter in the list? Thank you for your help!

Edit: Here's the CSV writer.

```
csv_out = open('file.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csv_out, dialect = 'excel-tab')
writer.writerows(list, list2, etc)
csv_out.close()
```

Comment: It would be best to eliminate the commas from the string entirely. I can live without them. Not a grammar stickler.

Comment: Show what the raw data looks like before you trying writing it at all

Comment: The example table above now more accurately reflects the raw data that I am scraping.

Comment: the csv module will quote if you are using it properly so without seeing what and how you are writing it is impossible to recommend anything

Comment: And does your xpath expression give you a two element list per row? If so, you can just csv.writer the stuff and it will get quoted for you.

Comment: Updated question examples to reflect questions from above comments.

Comment: You need  to keep the association with each column and use str.join, you cannot pass `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']` and expect python to know what belongs to which column. Your problem has nothing to do with the csv lib or delimiters, you have no association

Comment: Your xpath expressions are not extracting the data in a way that can be put back together in a sensible csv file, you're losing structure that is there. You should fix that.

Comment: pvg, are you saying that if I broaden the xpath to include tr and td in the string, I could use that information to sensibly put the table back together in the csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `csv` module to write your file. You can either choose a delimiter (such as |) or use quoting to handle the commas.

Let me know if you have further questions!

Comment: How is changing the delimiter going to change the string?

Comment: The default dialect (excel) in the csv module writer will quote by default so for the quoting case, one doesn't need to configure anything.